# Kaminari and page routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

I am using kaminari pagination on custom page but it generates /assets based url:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets?action=my&controller=blogs&page=2
```

I need:

```
http://localhost:3000/blogs/my?page=2
```

**Error:**

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using plain `paginate @blogs`? Does the error remain if you remove this code from your view? Kaminari generates links based on the current uri.

Comment: Nope, I have `= paginate @posts` . I have tried to pass params to `= paginate @posts, :params => { :controller => 'blogs', :action => 'my' }`, same broken links are generated. As I understand problem is in url_for method.

Comment: Could you write a part of routes.rb file with the routes used on this page?

Comment: After about two hours experiment, I finally realize this problem is not about kaminari. In my case, if I render `<%= url_for :controller => :admin %>`, it will render the `/assets?....`.

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same problem trying to set-up pagination with either Kaminari or Will_paginate for a custom action. It turned out that the problem was in my routes.rb file.

As an example, my custom action is called 'all_credit' in the 'cards' controller. Previously in routes.rb I had:

```
match '/cards_credit' => 'Cards#all_credit'
```

This was giving me the same behaviour you describe above and generating assets/ based urls.

By changing the line in routes.rb to:

```
match '/cards_credit(/:page)', :controller => 'cards', :action => 'all_credit'
```

I was able to solve this and the paginated links are now being generated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by add controller params.

```
<%= paginate @blog , :params => {:controller => "GoogleUsers"} %>
```